# ReactNative: _.native.createNavigationContainerRef is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

in my react-native app I'm trying to navigate from App.js where navigation is not yet ready, so I try to follow navigation docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

I copied example code as it is but I'm getting the following error:

```
_.native.createNavigationContainerRef is not a function / undefined
```

//RootNavigation

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

//App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That method was added in React Navigation 6.

```
npm uninstall @react-navigation/native
```

then install latest version

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/u2pc8c/comment/i4k3xb7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3